# Pi 3 GPIO reads true using pull-up, why?

Tags: gpio

It's my understanding that if a switch is wired to ground and the other to a GPIO pin you need a pull-up on the GPIO. Then the GPIO will usually read high and will usually read low when the switch is closed.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.input(16)
```

However, this appears to be the opposite for me. Using the code above my button, (connected to ground and GPIO 16) reads True/1 when pushed/pressed, why?

This is the button I'm using:

[image: push to release button]

Comment: Is it a latching button?

Comment: Do you mean it reads false when released and true when pressed? BTW a picture of a button is useless. If you have the part number or datasheet we can see if its a `Normally-Open` (**NO**) or `Normally Closed` (**NC**) Switch. No way to tell from a picture

Comment: @crasic sorry my question is a little dumb and I realise that a picture does not help.  Indeed, it reads 1 when pressed down and 0 when released. Should I assume that this is an always closed switch then (in release state)? would that be why?

Comment: @MrKnotts it's just a common option/variety of switch that is for sale. I have added an answer that will hopefully clear stuff up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches, relays, etc. come in `Normally Closed` (**NC**) or `Normally Open` (**NO**)  varieties,

[image]

You can easily check which one you have with a multimeter.

Many Switches come in both varieties and you choses when you order, its just a matter of electrical need, sometimes you need **NO** sometimes **NC**, if you want to know why this would matter I suggest asking another question here or on electronics.stackexchange.com .

However, all is not lost. You have the flexibility of inverting your logic, you may do this in code

```
read_value = !read_value
```

or you can do this in hardware

```
PU -> PD
Switch to 0V -> Switch to 3V3
```

And from your software POV it would be what you expect the value (`1` when released `0` when pressed)

Comment: Both of those switch actions are described as _momentary_ in that the change in connections that result in holding your mitt on the button is undone when you remove it - as well as the NO and NC descriptions they can also be described as OFF-(ON) and ON-(OFF) with the bracketed state being the _momentary_ one...